# All included players are not subscribed onesignal

Tags: android, json, web-services, push-notification, onesignal

I am using onesignal from my webservice to send push notification to an android app. everything was working properly but suddenly yesterday this service stopped and is returning:
`"{"id":"","recipients":0,"errors":["All included players are not subscribed"]}"     false`
What is this error? this is my posted json that I didn't change since yesterday:

```
    postString = "{""app_id"":""my_api"", ""tags"" : [{""key"": ""my_key"",
 ""relation"": ""="", ""value"": """ & my_key& """}] ,""data"" : {""contactName"" 
: """ & contactName & """ , ""phoneNumber"" : """ & phoneNumber & """,""latitude"" 
: """ & latitude & """, ""longitude"" : """ & longitude & """, ""messageType"" : 
""" & messageType & """,""MessageDate"" : """ & MessageDate & """ }, ""contents"" 
: {""en"" : """ & pushMessage & """ } }"
```

NB: 1- I tried to add ""included_segments"" : [""All""] but I still have the same problem

2- I checked some documentations and I found that case is sensitive for parameters ... , but in my case I didn't change anything and sending notifications was working fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Solved, there was a problem in onesignal service and it is fixed now

Comment: Would you explain how did you solve this problem? I am having the same problem.

Comment: In my case it was a problem from onesignal itself, suddenly something happened with their system and when they fixed it, things get back to work normally. I did not change anything from my side

Comment: Try ro contact onesignal support team as I did

Answer (score 1):

Two years late to the party, and this is probably fixed, but player-id's have to be sent to One signal in an array.